# java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using this tutorial to set up a Google Play Turn Based Multiplayer game: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

I've completed the tutorial and I think I did everything right, but I keep getting the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.

When I check logcat with no filters (I assume that's what it means by "logs"), the only related error I see is "Application ID (ReplaceMe) must be a numeric value. Please verify that your manifest refers to the correct project ID."

All locations where the application ID exists within my project have been replaced with my 12 digit application I created in the Developer Console, and when I search the project for "ReplaceMe", nothing shows up.

I've been pulling my hair out over this for two days. Any idea what I should do?

Below is my manifest and values/ids.xml

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mymikemiller.skeleton">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App" >
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

       <activity
          android:name="com.mymikemiller.skeleton.SkeletonActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

values/ids.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Insert your app id from the Developer Consoles -->
    <string name="app_id"><My 12 digit app id></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934727/error-in-setting-up-google-play-services-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you run, you're using the right configuration. The samples here:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples

have a bunch of projects that all open when you open the package. Make sure the you have the right configuration set or you'll run into errors because the other projects don't have the right App Id value set.